# Yum not working at all

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, repository

I ran the command `yum clean metadata` and then ran the command `yum update`. When I ran the yum update I now get the following errors

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from Red Hat Subscription Management.
rhel-6-server-eus-rpms                                                                                                                                                                                                | 3.7 kB     00:00
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/eus/rhel/server/6/6Server/i386/os/repodata/61d64ef221a0968bfefa27abbb584e44065b73cb-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/eus/rhel/server/6/6Server/i386/os/repodata/61d64ef221a0968bfefa27abbb584e44065b73cb-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/61d64ef221a0968bfefa27abbb584e44065b73cb-primary.sqlite.bz2 from rhel-6-server-eus-rpms: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I have no clue what would be causing this, does anyone have any input? I am running red hat 6.5

Comment: Given you have to pay to use RHEL, did your subscription expire? Did you ever have one?

Comment: Yes I have one and no it hasnt expired. I even reregistered the system to check it wasn't caused by that.

Comment: Then I would open a support ticket w/ RH, since you're paying for it, they can likely help you much quicker then we can 8-)

Comment: already opened one and still no response yet from them.

Comment: Fair enough. W/o a subscription it's difficult for others to replicate your issue.

Comment: That is true, so I am wondering mostly if anyone ran into this issue before, have tried all the redhat solutions online from their site i have access to and still none solved my problem.

Comment: There's really not much more to do, if you cannot access the URL then that would seem to be the place to focus on. Can you get into the URL using a browser? I get access denied. You could try `yum --verbose ...` to see if you get additional hints.

Comment: the url since it is rhel, but i can get the forbinden you are not allowed here message, eh i just need one rpm guess i might download it on another machine and upload and install it on the one it needs to be used on.

Comment: I've done that before as well.

Comment: Stupid question but do you get answer when you ping cdn.redhat.com from your server?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully your support case is already resolved, but just in case, try:

```
yum clean all
yum repolist -v
yum check-update
```

This should at least give you a little more information to work with.